# Android thread is not running in the background

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My Thread on Android is not running precisely.
I'm starting that from a Service, but somewhy it's not running correctly.

Service:

```
ServiceHelper sh = new ServiceHelper();
new Thread(sh).start();

public class ServiceHelper implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "run");
            //1.) sometimes it calls this here: SSLSocket.close();
            //2.) also, sometimes it calls a write operation on this SSLSocket.
            //    but since write can block, I've put this write operation inside an AsyncTask: new WriteAsyncTask().execute(somethingToWrite);
            //    This returns immediately.
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

And this results logcat like this:

```
01-10 22:39:54.148 I/TEST(10327): run
01-10 22:40:04.150 I/TEST(10327): run
```

So there are like 10 seconds that misses this thread.
Why could this happen?
There are other threads of course which do blocking network operations.
But why is this particular thread not running?

I also noticed a very strange thing:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "tick1");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "tick2");
    }
}
```

And somehow I get this in the log:

```
01-11 22:06:54.649 I/BGService(10078): tick1
01-11 22:07:50.664 I/BGService(10078): tick2
```

Between tick1 and tick2 there is one and only one operation: Thread.sleep(1000). How can it block for almost a minute?
It is in a Thread, which was started from a Service, but what is the main reason for this huge delay?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with a thread.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to show you a very basic reduction of my app. However, the thread that's printing messages into logcat in each second looks the same.

Comment: So for more browsing it seems that SSLSocket.close() can block the whole tread.

Comment: I updated the original question. I'm stuck at this point now.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure sure you run your Runnable like so:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ServiceHelper());
t.start();
```

Only then will it be started with as a thread.

On a side note, what you are doing is running an infinite loop which will take 100% CPU usage. It's possible that Android will kill or heavily throttle your service to allow other services to run properly.

Comment: I've corrected the question, sorry. Of course there was a sleep inside originally.

Comment: Did anything interesting happen in the logs during those 10 seconds? Many times Android will kill + restart your service when memory is low.

Comment: No, there is no single line between those 2. I know about service restart thing of Android. but my service logs its startup, and is not presented between those lines, so it's not that case.

Answer (score -1):

Inside of the while loop use something like this and you will see the results

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```